# How to change a field data after time t in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to change the data in table automatically after time i.
Say time i = 10 sec.
Table t, has column x1,x2,x3.
x3 is boolean as datatype. x3'll be false by

Now suppose I changed the value in t.x3 (any row) to True then after 10 sec it should change itself to False.

Is it possible.? By some trigger or cursor or procedure or something? 
Alteast need a keyword to google it.
Thank You!

Comment: You can use `trigger` for this. Any specific reason for the 10 sec delay?

Comment: Yeah need user ideal time using sql server. And some more calculations on that.!

Comment: I think you should use "job" for that, or at least to reach the similar solution for your request.

Comment: I ain't understood what u wrote @ShaiEitan

Comment: The solution or at least a way to solve the time interval is to use a JOB. Since you asked "something" to search for, @ShaiEitan gave you that!

Comment: in MSSQL you have an option to create something that called Job. 

Sometimes we have a T-SQL process that we need to run that takes some time to run or we want to run it during idle time on the server. you could create a SQL Agent job manually.

Comment: oh, I need some these type of keywords, now I'll google it. Thanks @ShaiEitan

Comment: Thanks, I actually need that. How it works. @JorgeCampos

Comment: Please read this article:
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job)

Comment: Data that changes itself unexpectedly in a database is highly unusual. Are you certain this isn't an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)? Explain what the underlying requirement is here so people can advise a proper course of action. Something very peculiar is going on here IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a trigger.  Just use a computed column.

For instance:

```
create table t (dte datetime,
                flag as (case when dte < dateadd(second, -10, getdate()) then 0 else 1
                         end)
               );
```

This is a computed column.  It will recalculate when it is queried, doing the calculation you are asking for.

Comment: Gordon,  nice I thought about computed column but I was not sure if was calculated at execution time. Thanks about clarify it!

Answer (score 1):

This scenario you are asking for **looks like an anti-pattern**. Exists a command to wait for random amount of time ( `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';` ) but, usually, [is not a good idea to use it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql):

> **Caution+**
>
> Including WAITFOR will slow the completion of the SQL Server process and can result in a timeout message in the application. If necessary, adjust the timeout setting for the connection at the application level.

In my opinion, the easy way is to create a view over your table and calculate the field on the fly:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( PrimaryKey ....,
                 x3 bit, 
                 t datetime default gettime(), 
               );

CREATE VIEW v as
SELECT PrimaryKey,
       (CASE WHEN x3 = 1 and datediff(second,  t, getdate()) > 10 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
        END ) as x3  --<-- lets supose this is your field.
FROM t;
```

Then, you can select from view to check for your calculate field:

```
SELECT x3 FROM v; --<-- select from v instead from t.
```

You can use a trigger to keep `t` field up to date on change x3:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateModified
ON dbo.t
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
   UPDATE dbo.t
   SET t = getdate()
   FROM Inserted i
   WHERE dbo.t.PrimaryKey = i.PrimaryKey
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to automatically update the values after something has changed on the table. But this change will be affected within milliseconds as the trigger executes straight after the update/insert/delete.

The second method you can do is to create a scheduled Database job which will run every 10 seconds (In this case) or any specific interval, which will make the updates in the required columns.

Refer this [Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.110).aspx) for more information on scheduling the DB Jobs